# create dynamic dropdown list using append in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, append

Hi when I'm using static code into jquery for create dynamic dropdown list using append() then its working, like

```
$('#optionNameCity')
     .empty()
     .append('<option selected="selected" value="Wakad">Wakad</option><option value="Hinjewadi"> Hinjewadi </option>');
}
```

but when I'm using php script for create dynamic list then its failure and not showing any output, like

```
$('#optionNameCity')
     .empty()
     .append($(<?php include('db.php');$loc= mysql_query("select city from location");while($row=mysql_fetch_array($loc)){echo "<option selected='selected' value='".$row['city']."'>" . $row['city'] . "</option>";}?>));
             }
```

Please guide me where I'm going wrong.

Thanks

Comment: remove `$` from this line : `.append($`

Comment: Still its not working :(

Comment: @ShubhamVerma have you got any error on console?

Comment: @HüseyinBABAL no any error showing

Comment: @PratikJoshi HTML code is
<div id="localityindex"><span>Location:</span>                    <select id="optionNameCity" class="city"><option value="Wakad">Wakad</option><option value="Hinjewadi"> Hinjewadi </option></select>

Comment: Try echo '<option selected="selected" value='".$row['city']."'>' . $row['city'] . '</option>';

Answer (score 0):

```
  <?php include('db.php');
      $loc= mysql_query("select city from location");
      $cityList="";
        while($row=mysql_fetch_array($loc))
       {
          $cityList="<option selected='selected' value='".$row['city']."'>" . $row['city']."</option>";
       }
  ?>
  <?php if($cityList!=""){ ?>
     $('#optionNameCity option').remove();               
     $('#optionNameCity).append("<?php echo $citylist; ?>");
  <?php } ?>
```

Replace your code with above code

Comment: Thanks for your reply @user3168720 but when I'm using this code its still not working, can you please used it with jquery?

Comment: check my answer again , i made changes in jquery part please replace and try it